# Connecting to Mongodb in Spring boot with Wildfly 21 JNDI object-factory

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, wildfly, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to connect to mongodb using wildfly jndi in springboot war application and it is throwing following casting exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'java:global/MyMongoClient' is expected to be of type 'com.mongodb.client.MongoClient' but was actually of type 'com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl'
```

Wildfly 21 Standalone.xml object-factory:

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
        <bindings>
            <object-factory name="java:global/MyMongoClient" module="org.mongodb" class="com.mongodb.client.MongoClientFactory">
                <environment>
                    <property name="connectionString" value="mongodb://localhost:27017"/>
                </environment>
            </object-factory>
        </bindings>
        <remote-naming/>
    </subsystem>
```

Wildfly 21 mongodb module configurations:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.mongodb">  
   <resources>  
        <resource-root path="mongodb-driver-sync-4.6.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar"/>          
        <resource-root path="bson-4.6.1.jar"/>         
   </resources>  
   <dependencies>  
       <module name="javax.api"/>  
       <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>  
       <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>  
   </dependencies>
```

Java code to look up jndi:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:global/MyMongoClient")
private MongoClient mongoClient;
```

not even working with context lookup:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
mongoClient = (MongoClient) ctx.lookup("java:global/MyMongoClient");
```

I even then try to use direct implemented class rather than interface:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:global/MyMongoClient")
private MongoClientImpl mongoClient;
```

Still same error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'java:global/MyMongoClient' is expected to be of type 'com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl' but was actually of type 'com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl'
```

I'm using Spring boot 2.7.13, Java 11, Wildfly 21, mongo-driver 4.6.1, spring-data-mongodb 3.4.13 and mongodb 3.2

Need you guys perspective what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

After few days of head scratching, it was identified MongoClient class was being loaded by multiple ClassLoaders as I added dependency in application pom.xml and on wildfly same mongo java driver jars were placed on server module as well.

fixed this with following changes in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
         <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
               <Dependencies>org.mongodb</Dependencies>
            </manifestEntries>
         </archive>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```